# C# procedural generation- how to do always a set number?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, procedural-generation, procedural

Ok, Working in Unity here and trying to get out this core game dynamic. Basically I have all these 3D platforms that have certain weights to them (weight meaning how often they appear in the array from which game can select next platform) -

right now each platform has a set of the 4 cardinal directions (plus up/down but all have those) where it can spawn the next platform for player to walk onto, else they fall. This is an enum and I set this manually.

Before player first steps on a platform, it is halfway alpha, so it just looks like a marker. After they step, it turns 1 alpha and thus doesn't look like a "marker", see here:

[image]

As the player walks via joystick, I want the platforms to spawn in square "tiers" - say of length 10 platforms - and I'll do something when tier is full. My problem is I've tried a bunch of different systems but do not know how to implement this. Model picture where there are different configurations but ultimately a 10x10 limit/bounds:

[image]

Here's my method of spawning based on direction - problem is direction is subjective, based on player object's point of view:

```
foreach(Direction d in directionsAvailable)
        {
            Vector3 pos = transform.position;
            float dist = container.GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.x;

            switch (d) {
            case Direction.Backward:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x, pos.y, pos.z-dist);
                break;
            case Direction.Forward:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x, pos.y, pos.z+dist);
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x-dist, pos.y, pos.z);
                break;
            case Direction.Right:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x+dist, pos.y, pos.z);
                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x, pos.y-(2*dist), pos.z);
                break;
            case Direction.Up:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x, pos.y+(2*dist), pos.z); //hits itself, might have to do more dist
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
```

Here is how I test if a platform is at a position or position is open:

```
public Platform PlatAtPos(Vector3 pos)
    {
        platformsSpawned = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Platform>();
        foreach(Platform p in platformsSpawned)
        {
            if(p.originPos == pos || p.transform.position == pos) //or just delete one of them
            {
                return p;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
public void checkForPlatsAround()
    {
        gameController = GameObject.FindObjectOfType<GameController> ();
        float dist = container.GetComponent<Renderer> ().bounds.size.x;
        foreach (Platform.Direction dir in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Platform.Direction))) {
        Vector3 pos = transform.position;

            switch (dir) {
            case Direction.Backward:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x, pos.y, pos.z-dist);
                break;
            case Direction.Forward:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x, pos.y, pos.z+dist);
                break;
            case Direction.Left:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x-dist, pos.y, pos.z);
                break;
            case Direction.Right:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x+dist, pos.y, pos.z);
                break;
            case Direction.Down:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x, pos.y-(2*dist), pos.z);
                break;
            case Direction.Up:
                pos = new Vector3 (pos.x, pos.y+(2*dist), pos.z); //hits itself, might have to do more dist
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            if(gameController.PlatAtPos(pos) != null)
            {
                gameController.PlatAtPos (pos).showAsMarker ();
            }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better/clearer way to go about this? How can I do this procedurally?

Comment: `transform.forward`?

Comment: Based on the player Objects point of view, you can get the players right, left forward and back.  All using his transform.  So forward would be like Draco mentioned in his comment.  `transform.forward transform.right transform.back transform.left transform.up transform.down`  You mention doing this procedurally but I am not quite sure what you are trying to do procedurally? Generating the level or just creating all the stepping stones procedurally?